# How do I generate asconfig.texi when compiling GNU binutils' gas from git cloned source?

Tags: makefile, compilation, binutils, texinfo

I have cloned the binutils-gdb repository from git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git, checked out the tag `binutils-2_40` (commit `32778522c7d8777803c88684b8e428ee729f0b22`), in a separate directory run `../../binutils-gdb/configure` which generated a large `Makefile`, then run `make all-gas`, and I eventually get the error `cp: cannot create regular file 'doc/asconfig.texi': No such file or directory`.

I have "texi2any (GNU texinfo) 7.0.2" which I (only vaguely) understand is required, but the failing command is `cp`, so it's as if the makefile isn't building some prerequisite file for the target.

In the tarball of 2.40 from the FTP, `gas/doc/asconfig.texi` exists, but it doesn't in the repository.

How can I successfully compile the project?

I'm aware there are some workarounds possible, which I'm tempted to follow because I don't even care that much about the documentation in this form anyway, but I dunno - I feel like `configure && make && make install` should work properly, and therefore that I'm missing something obvious.

The end of the `make` output is as follows:

```
Making all in po
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas/po'
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/es | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/es.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/fi | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/fi.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/fr | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/fr.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/id | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/id.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/ja | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/ja.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/ru | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/ru.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/rw | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../..
/../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/rw.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/sv | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/sv.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/tr | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/tr.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/uk | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/uk.po
file=`echo ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/zh_CN | sed 's,.*/,,'`.gmo \
  && rm -f $file && PATH=../src:$PATH /usr/bin/msgfmt -o $file ../../../../binutils-gdb/gas/po/zh_CN.po
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas/po'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas'
  GEN      doc/asconfig.texi
cp: cannot create regular file 'doc/asconfig.texi': No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [Makefile:2234: doc/asconfig.texi] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1664: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1010: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/asday/code/src/github.com/asday/osdev-barebones/build/binutils/gas'
make: *** [Makefile:5475: all-gas] Error 2
binutils $
```

The target at the top of that traceback is as follows:

```
doc/asconfig.texi: doc/$(CONFIG).texi doc/$(am__dirstamp)
    $(AM_V_at)rm -f doc/asconfig.texi
    $(AM_V_GEN)cp $(srcdir)/doc/$(CONFIG).texi doc/asconfig.texi
    $(AM_V_at)chmod u+w doc/asconfig.texi
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug within the repo and that's why your seeing the issue.  It was resolved in a recent commit ([8034b0baeac1b209b1742b3e8fa25015191b57b8](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=8034b0baeac1b209b1742b3e8fa25015191b57b8)).  It was missing the `-p` argument when copying the file.  If you checkout the repo during that commit or any commit afterwards that should work.  I just tried it out on my end and I was able to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the -p to the cp did not work for me. I removed the empty file gas/doc/.dirstamp that was not part of previous builds and isn't in the master branch or 2.40_branch and my make now works.